# How to get utf-8 bytes in of emoji?

Tags: python-3.x

How would I get the actual character points for an emoji in python3?

```
>>> ''
''

>>> ?
\xF0\x9F\x98\x8B
```

And then, vice-versa, how would I print the emoji from code points?

```
>>> print ('\xF0\x9F\x98\x8B')
''
```

This was the behavior in python2.7 but not in 3 so curious how to do it here.

---

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Nov 13 2021, 06:17:34)
>>> ''
'\xf0\x9f\x98\x8b'
>>> print('\xf0\x9f\x98\x8b')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string/bytes default `decode` / `encode` methods:

```
>>> ''.encode('utf-8')
b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x80'
>>> b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x80'.decode('utf-8')
''
```